# Do you know why I am receiving "not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<(string | undefined)[]>'."

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I created a Const using React with Typescript and I am receiving an error message

```
"Argument of type 'string | never[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<(string | undefined)[]>'."
```

The error message is appearing on the line below `setCustomerIdValue(defaultCustomerIdValues)`
But I believe the issue is where I am defining defaultCustomerIDValues

```
const defaultCustomerIdValues = getShipCompanyNameFromCustomerIdValues(
          customerIds,
          defaulValues.customerIds
        )
```

Here is all of the coded including the function `getShipCompanyNameFromCustomerIdValues` which I believe the error is coming from:

```
     const [customerIdValue, setCustomerIdValue] = useState<(string | undefined)[]>([])
      useEffect(() => {
        const defaultCustomerIdValues = getShipCompanyNameFromCustomerIdValues(
          customerIds,
          defaulValues.customerIds
        )                
         setCustomerIdValue(defaultCustomerIdValues)
      }, [defaulValues.customerIds])


    const getShipCompanyNameFromCustomerIdValues = (
      allIds: CustomerIDShipCompanyID[] | undefined,
      searchIds: (string | undefined)[] | undefined
    ) => {
      if (allIds === undefined || searchIds === undefined) return []

      let result: string[] = []
      searchIds.forEach((v: string | undefined) => {
        const id = allIds.find((id: CustomerIDShipCompanyID) => id.value === v)
        if (id?.ShipCompanyName) result.push(id?.ShipCompanyName)
     })
  
      return [...new Set(result)].join(', ')
    }

    export interface CustomerIDShipCompanyID {
      customerId: string
      ShipCompanyName: string
      value?: string
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Jesse and welcome to SO. Generally speaking when TS shouts for different types, an easy way to solve things is to give it the types it wants.
Have you tried...?

```
const [customerIdValue, setCustomerIdValue] = useState<(string | never[])[]>([])
```